# Awk - using an array with multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm new to shell scripting, and I need to compute an average file1, and then the average of the result and a number in file2, so far i came up with this, but it doesn't print anything.

```
awk '{if ($FILENAME == "spring") array[$1]=($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8)/7; if($FILENAME == "fall") array[$1]=(array[$1]+$2)/2 }  END { for (var in array) print var,array[var]}' ./spring ./fall
```

Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: To get a decent answer you need to post both files and the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There are no sigils in awk.  Try dropping the `$`:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ /spring/ { array[$1]=($2+$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8)/7 }
   FILENAME ~ /fall/ { array[$1]=(array[$1]+$2)/2 }  
   END { for (var in array) print var,array[var]}' ./spring ./fall
```

In short, `FILENAME` is the name of the file currently being processed, but `$FILENAME` is equivalent to `$0` when FILENAME starts with a letter.

Comment: FILENAME is including the path, so `FILENAME == "./spring"`.

Comment: @WalterA Good catch.  Not sure how an answer can go this long with such an error!  Editing to be slightly more robust

Answer (score 1):

How about `awk '{s+=$1}ENDFILE{print FILENAME,s/FNR;s=0}' RS=" " file1 file2`:

```
$ cat file1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

$ cat file2
1 2

$ awk '{s+=$1}ENDFILE{print FILENAME,s/FNR;s=0}' RS=" " file1 file2
file1 4.5
file2 1.5
```